# Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'new' in field list

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm creating a database, where I validate input data with triggers. I added them successfully, but there is an error when I try to input fine data.

creating db, tables and triggers

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBWorkers;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ludzie(
PESEL char(11) NOT NULL,
imie varchar(30) NOT NULL,
nazwisko varchar(30) NOT NULL,
data_urodzenia date NOT NULL,
wzrost float NOT NULL,
waga float NOT NULL,
rozmiar_buta int NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY(PESEL));

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION check_pesel(PESEL char(11)) RETURNS bool
BEGIN
IF(
    CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.PESEL) <> 11 AND
    CONVERT(PESEL, SIGNED INT) > 0 AND
    CONVERT(LEFT(PESEL,2), SIGNED INT) BETWEEN 0 AND 99 AND
    CONVERT(SUBSTRING(PESEL,3,2), SIGNED INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 12 AND
    CONVERT(SUBSTRING(PESEL,3,2), SIGNED INT) BETWEEN 1 AND     DAY(LAST_DAY(CONCAT('19',LEFT(PESEL,2),'-',SUBSTRING(PESEL,3,2),'-01')))
    )
    THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
        RETURN FALSE;
END IF;
END $$

CREATE TRIGGER `ludzie_data_check_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Ludzie`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NOT(
        check_pesel(NEW.PESEL) AND
        NEW.WZROST > 0.0 AND
        NEW.WAGA > 0.0 AND
        NEW.ROZMIAR_BUTA > 0
    )
THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check on Ludzie failed during insert';
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to input data by

```
INSERT INTO Ludzie VALUES ('7810396705', 'Anders', 'Kennedy','1958-08-20', 1.70, 88.6, 43)
```

I get

```
Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'new' in field list
```

I already tried turning mysql server on and off, checked if I'm doing it to the right database. Everything seems to look fine, but it isn't :/

Comment: Not that it necessarily matters, but just in case, what version of MySQL are your running?

Comment: 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found your problem:

```
CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.PESEL) <> 11 AND
CONVERT(PESEL, SIGNED INT) > 0 AND
```

That is inconsistent usage of NEW.PESEL and PESEL, you should not use the keyword new in a function that does not add anything to the database.  In this context, the error recognized NEW as a table instead of a keyword.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I dont know how i could be that blind :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, After doing some reading I as well am willing to bet that the "NEW" keyword is not needed in

CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.PESEL).

NEW keyword is used in update and insert commands.